# How to upload a file with specific extension only?

Tags: php, file-upload

I want to only upload a file with extension name `.mp3`.

I tried to upload file with this code:

`index.php`:

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" id="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>

<input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Upload Image">
</form>
```

`upload.php`:

```
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
if ($extension == "mp3"){
    $target = "upload/";
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target. $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
}
else {
    echo "Failed";
}
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: what's the value of $_FILES["file"]["name"]?

Comment: Can you define `its not working` please

Comment: Do you mean, you always get to `"Failed"`?

Comment: I can't see any glaring syntax errors so far, so I think this might be a configuration error (i.e. `max_file_size` is too small). Please elaborate on what error you are getting so that I can cast off my uncertainties.

As an aside, consider putting file extension restrictions on the client side too using the `input`'s [`accept`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_accept.asp) attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
$name = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
$extension = end((explode(".", $name))); //extra () to prevent notice

if ($extension == "mp3"){
    $target = "upload/";
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target. $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
}
else {
    echo "Failed";
}
```

This should work. Make sure about proper value into `$_FILES["file"]["name"]`

You can also use [pathinfo()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php). For example:

```
$path_parts = pathinfo($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = $path_parts['extension'];
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a case of string case comparison. Comparing in lower or upper format should work.

```
$temp = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
$extension = strtolower($temp);
if ($extension == "mp3"){
    $target = "upload/";
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target. $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
}
else {
    echo "Failed";
}
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: Well perhaps I thought the character comparison might be the issue here. And I have explained what I am trying to suggest.

I will try to be more specific in future. I am a newbie to StackOverflow so please bare with me.

Answer (score 0):

I think OP has missed the form type in the form tag. Below is the tested code:

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST)){
    $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    $extension = end($temp);
    if ($extension == "mp3"){
        $target = "upload/";
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target. $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    }
    else {  
        echo "Failed";  
    }
}
?>

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type='file' name='file'/>
<input type='submit' name='submit'/>
</form>
```